# Different sort-by by one key Clojure

Tags: clojure

Hey I have this Code but I would like to reverse only the :a key.

```
(sort-by (juxt :a :b) [{:a 1 :b 3} {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 2 :b 1}])
;;=> [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 3} {:a 2 :b 1}]
```

I tried this but this was in the wrong order.

```
(sort-by (juxt :a :b) #(compare %2 %1)  [{:a 1 :b 3} {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 2 :b 1}])
;;=> ({:a 2, :b 1} {:a 1, :b 3} {:a 1, :b 2})
```

I would like to get.

```
;;=> ({:a 2, :b 1} {:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 3})
```

Any Ideas?
Can I do this also in juxt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(sort-by (juxt (comp - :a) :b) [{:a 1 :b 3} {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 2 :b 1}])
```

Answer (score 2):

This and related questions about comparators and sorting in Clojure are covered in this guide article: https://clojure.org/guides/comparators

Answer (score 0):

You can try the thread last macro to sort first by `:b` then sort in reverse by `:a`.

```
(->> [{:a 1 :b 3} {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 2 :b 1}]
     (sort-by :b)
     (sort-by :a #(compare %2 %1)))
```